# Sexual desires in heaven?

Tags: jannah, eschatology

Ok so i have a a few questions about the nature if heaven.

1.why would there be sexual desires in heaven? The purpose of sexual desires and marriage is to facilitate the propagation of a species. So why do we assume we will have these urges in heaven when we will be immortal in heaven? And aren't we supposed to be cleansed our earthly vices in heaven?

2. Does it specifically say anywhere in the quran and hadiths that the purpose of the houris in heaven is sex? Many people I've met regard them as toys made for their pleasure and many people look forward to heaven just to have sex with these creatures.

3.why do many people say that certain desires and feelings would be removed from us in heaven but 1... Namely sexual desires would and should be still in us. Some examples ive seen here and elsewhere are: when someone asks jf they can play video games in heaven they get told that they wouldn't want to play video games in heaven because the desire would be removed (why doesn't this apply to sex).
Another question i read was about a woman asking if she can have her husband to herself and someone pointed out that if this contradicts with her husband's wishes then god would remove the feelings of envy from her but didn't even consider the option of god removing the husbands feelings of envy.
3.what is the nature of heaven in general? Is it spiritual or carnal? I have always thought of heaven as spiritual and transcendental.

Ive meet many people with the attitude that if they cant have orgies in heaven then there is no point in going there heaven.

Comment: At that point, you might as well ask why there would be food in heaven since no one will need food to live. Obviously, things do not need to exist only for their "evolutionary purpose," but also because people enjoy doing them. People *like* eating, that is why Allah created food in heaven.